# NameError on Global 'Key Position' Variable, and ax.cla() majorly slowing things down - Matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a big dataframe that consists of one X column (wavelength) and 73 Y columns (Spec1-73). I am trying to create a code to flip through the plots contained in this dataframe utilizing Matplotlib, plotting the x and a singular y on each plot in sequence, and keeping the axes consistent.

I am utilizing a key event function in order to use the arrow key to give direction through the plots, starting with x-Wavelength and y-Spec1, going then to x-Wavelength and y-Spec2, etc. However, I keep getting `NameError: name 'curr_pos' is not defined` when I try to run the code and key over to the next plot. I've tried to define `curr_pos` only in the function which allows me to key to the next plot, but it only goes one forward and one backwards then repeats the same plots if I try to go one farther in either direction (telling me that something is wrong with `curr_pos`).

Furthermore, it's not really possible for me to use `ax.cla()` because it slows down the code to an unbearable degree, and doesn't maintain the same axes (which is important to see trends). Does anyone know why that is?

I have attached my code and a sample of what my dataframe looks like below. Forgive me if this is a duplicate - I tried the questions that StackOverflow recommended me, but they weren't very useful. Thanks so much for the help! :)

```py
def manual():
    date = '20200121'
    QD = 'QD053'

    path = all_DATA_DIR + '\\' + date + '\\' + QD + '\\' + 'CSVs'
    data_dir = os.path.join(path)
    for filename in os.listdir(data_dir):
        if not filename.startswith('Pol'):
            continue

        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, filename), header=0, engine='python', index_col=None,
                         sep=',')

        t = df['Wavelength'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])
        y1 = df['Spec1'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])

        plots = []
        for x in range(1, 74):
            plots.append((df['Wavelength'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2]), df['Spec' + str(x)].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])))

        curr_pos = 0

        def key_event(e):
            global curr_pos

            if e.key == "right":
                curr_pos = curr_pos + 1
            elif e.key == "left":
                curr_pos = curr_pos - 1
            else:
                return
            curr_pos = curr_pos % len(plots)

            # ax.cla()
            ax.plot(plots[curr_pos][0], plots[curr_pos][1], alpha=0.6)
            fig.canvas.draw()

        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_event)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5000))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
        ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.3, color='grey')
        ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, color='grey')
        ax.set_ylim([-1000, 60000])
        plt.xticks(rotation=70)

        ax.plot(t, y1)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manual()
```

[image: Sample DF]

Answer (score 0):

The brief code below alone gives
`SyntaxError: name 'curr_pos' is assigned to before global declaration`.
The error is different from yours, but this may be related with the rest of the code you have, and an indicator that the `global ...` may be a source of error.
It is best if you also show which line throws the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    #import sys, os
    curr_pos = 0
    #global curr_pos
    curr_pos = curr_pos + 1
    return

if (__name__ == '__main__' ) :
    main()
```

Comment: I think the issue stemmed from the fact that it has to be called a global variable outside of the function first, which is odd to me. I posted my solution as an answer in case anyone needed it. It's ugly code, but it works! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well after wrestling with it for awhile, this is the (ugly, but functional) solution I came up with.

```py
def plot_controls(ax):
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(yaxismultiple))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(xaxismultiple))
    ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.3, color='grey', alpha=.5)
    ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, color='grey', alpha=.5)
    ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
    plt.xticks(rotation=xtickrotation)
    plt.title('Spectrum #' + str(curr_pos + 1))
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=.24)


def manual():
    data_dir = os.path.join(path)
    for filename in os.listdir(data_dir):
        if not filename.startswith('Pol'):
            continue

        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, filename), header=0, engine='python', index_col=None,
                         sep=',')
        t = df['Wavelength'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])
        y1 = df['Spec1'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])

        plots = []
        for x in range(1, 74):
            plots.append((df['Wavelength'].drop(index=[0, 1, 2]), df['Spec' + str(x)].drop(index=[0, 1, 2])))

        global curr_pos
        curr_pos = 0

        def key_event(e):
            global curr_pos
            if e.key == "right":
                curr_pos = curr_pos + 1
            elif e.key == "left":
                curr_pos = curr_pos - 1
            else:
                return
            curr_pos = curr_pos % len(plots)
            ax.cla()
            ax.plot(plots[curr_pos][0], plots[curr_pos][1])
            plot_controls(ax)
            fig.canvas.draw()

        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_event)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plot_controls(ax)
        ax.plot(t, y1)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manual()
```